# Need help SPECIFYING a list to hide from mobile view

Tags: css, wordpress, css-selectors, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm using Wordpress & trying to specify a list to hide from mobile view in the "additional css" part of the Wordpress site. I've attached a screenshot of the the tree below. (It's the list under div id="footer-8")

[image]

The code I've used so far is but it hasn't seemed to have do anything!

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #footer-shape-holder li.single-shape shape1 {
    visibility: hidden;
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px auto 5px 20px;
    width: 28%;
    display: none;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a ID instead of class there, and .shape1 is not a child of .single-shape try this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
   .footer-shape-holder .single-shape.shape1 {
       display: none;
   }
}
```